# Keeping slideshow on top with page below visible

Tags: javascript, highslide

I have a pretty big Intranet site at work, there are detailed work descriptions. There are links in the procedure that bring up pics, and I'm using Highslide. The default behavior is to bring the gallery up and dim the background. When you click outside the gallery it closes. Some of my users would like to keep a gallery up, on top so they can follow the procedure. As of now they keep having to bring the gallery up. I also have a  pop up on a section of another page that pops up a modal with html in it(I have calculators popping up). The behaviors of these is they stay on top of the page until you close them. I'd like the same behavior for my gallery, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

A Highslide gallery/image can stay open exactly like an Highslide HTML popup. All you need to do, is removing the [hs.dimmingOpacity](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.dimmingOpacity) setting for your gallery. Since I haven't seen your page, I can't tell where to find this setting in your gallery setup.

Comment: That should work. Please give us a link to your site - there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 1):

Highslide lets you define a function to run before closing. If this function returns true, it will close, if false, it will stay open.  Without seeing your code this is the best response I can offer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var allowClose=false;
hs.Expander.prototype.onBeforeClose = function (sender) {
   return allowClose;
}
</script>
```

The somewhere else you can add a button to switch allowClose to true, which will restore the basic closing functionality.  There is also a close() function in highslide, so you could have a large button somewhere to call close().

The full set of properties, functions, and events is here-> http://highslide.com/ref/

Comment: Not necessary. RoadRash's reply is the correct one.

Comment: OP wants the gallery to stay open when they click outside of it. Changing the opacity will let you see what's behind the gallery, but I think a click will still close it.  I think he might need a combination of the two answers.

Comment: No, it won't. See the barebones example: http://highslide.com/examples/white-10px.html. Clicking outside the expander does nothing. Ditto for a gallery: http://highslide.com/examples/gallery-white.html.

Comment: Yeah you're right, and roadrash made highslide right? so roadrash should know the answer.  I wonder why it's not working for them.

Comment: RoadRash has done a lot of support, but isn't the developer. But yeah, we need a link to the OP's page to see what's happening. I never understand why people are "coy" about giving us a link!

Comment: They don't want to "give away" that amazing intellectual property that they've built using an open source plugin and supported with numerous questions on free coding forums!  But in this case, with the discussion of following procedures, it sounds like it's a private intranet or something we're not supposed to view.